# Using multiple parsers while scraping a page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have searched some of the questions regarding this topic but i couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm currently trying to use multiple parsers on a site depending on the product  I want to search. After trying some methods, I ended up with this:

With this start request:

```
def start_requests(self):

    txtfile = open('productosABuscar.txt', 'r')

    keywords = txtfile.readlines()

    txtfile.close()

    for keyword in keywords:

        yield Request(self.search_url.format(keyword))
```

That gets into my normal parse_item.

What i want to do is, with this parse_item (by checking with the item category like laptop, tablet, etc):

```
def parse_item(self,response):
        #I get the items category for the if/else
    category = re.sub('Back to search results for |"','', response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@class, "a-list-item")]//a/text())').extract_first())
        #Get the product link, for example (https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-T430s-Performance-Professional-Refurbished/dp/B07L4FR92R/ref=sr_1_7?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1545829464&sr=1-7&keywords=laptop)
    urlProducto = response.request.url

        #This can be done in a nicer way, just trying out if it works atm
    if category == 'Laptop':

        yield response.follow(urlProducto, callback = parse_laptop)
```

With:

```
def parse_laptop(self, response):

    #Parse things
```

Any suggestions? The error i get when running this code is 'parse_laptop' is not defined. I have already tried putting the parse_laptop above the parse_item and i still get the same error.

Comment: You should use `callback=self.parse_laptop`, `productosABuscar.txt` contains a list of every detail product or every category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield response.follow(urlProducto, callback = parse_laptop)`
This is the request and here's you function `def parse_laptop(self, response):` you probably have noticed that you `parse_laptop` function requires self object.
so please modify you request to :
`yield response.follow(urlProducto, callback = self.parse_laptop)`
This should do the work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to a method and not a function, so just change it like this:

```
yield response.follow(urlProducto, callback = self.parse_laptop)
```